# embedded glassfish - activation.jar

Tags: java-ee-6, glassfish-3, javax.activation

I need to use javax.activation to get the mimetype of files.  I am running embedded glassfish and added the activation jar to the maven plugin as a dependency; however, it is still returning application/octet-stream which indicates to me that the jar is not in the right location.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Walter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a better API which actually reads the file type: Apache Tika.

Walter

Comment: Was it provided with the embedded glassfish?

Comment: No, Tika is a solution along with some other one JBoss uses for its content repositories.  That is not a spec provided in JavaEE, but something JCR implementations do, so if you follow the bigger JCR implementations, you get Tika and a JBoss one.

Comment: Ok, but did you need that lib in the embedded glassfish or it didn't matter?

Comment: Oh, I see the confusion - there is primitive support in java itself which I later found to be inadequate, that was the activation jar.  No, Tika just needs to be on the classpath for the application that needs it.

Comment: If you ever end up needing some libs (eclipselink?) in your embedded GF: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670701/using-different-eclipselink-than-bundled-in-glassfish-embedded-web/20548417#20548417