# Using different eclipselink than bundled in glassfish-embedded-web

Tags: glassfish, eclipselink, glassfish-embedded

I use glassfish-embedded-web for integration tests inside a maven project:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.2-b06</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

glassfish-embedded-web comes with Eclipselink 2.2.0, but the project requires features of 2.4. For regular deployment, this is solved by adding je required jars to glassfish's modules directory and this dependency:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.core</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I tried also compile scope, still the embedded EL 2.2.0 is used. Adding a test scope dependency on EL 2.4.1 doesn't help. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Did u end up with a feasible solution?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to specify the maven scope **test**? Otherwise it will not be available while testing! To only provide this version for testing you could use maven profiles.

Comment: I tried that. Compilation results in "package org.eclipse.persistence.annotations does not exist" error. This package is in org.eclipse.persistence.core

Comment: Oh sorry didn't read that you already tried compile and test scope. I'm using the `org.glassfish.main.extras:glassfish-embedded-all:3.1.2.2` and it works when I use the provided scope for eclipse link.

Answer (score 0):

I see two possible solutions to this problem: either you **build your own glassfish-embedded** or you just use a brute force approach and **modify the jar**.

**On the 1st approach:**
After spending some time building GF I figured that even with my dilettante shell scripting skills its easier to just use the second approach instead of figuring GF code. However, if you're up for this one I'd suggest to start at [oracle wiki](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/GlassFish/FullBuildInstructions).

**On the 2nd approach:** As I've mentioned above, automating this task is the best approach in my opinion (at least if you're dealing with numerous libs and continuous changes), so I wrote [this](https://gist.github.com/nyxcalamity/7916644) script with all the necessary instructions on how to use it. After you get the new jar just [install](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html) it in your local repo. I'm using [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/) so for me it was a matter of couple buttons getting pressed.

P.S.: Any comments/advices/improvements on the script are welcome.